# formatting json results

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

I'm using this demo to try and get data to display on my page using JSON. The images display, but how can I get it to display each image in it's own list item tag with a unique ID?

Like

```
<li id="20393"> picture </li>


        $.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?",
    {
        tags: "mount rainier",
        tagmode: "any",
        format: "json"
    },
    function (data) {
        $.each(data.items, function (i, item) {
            $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#images");
            if (i == 3) return false;
        });
    });
```

Thanks

Comment: Why is this code: `if (i == 3) return false;`? Is it voluntary? Also, what is the element with id `images`?

Comment: it's just from the demo I was using on http://api.jquery.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same way you are constructing the `img`, wrap it with an identified `li` ([api.jqueryui.com/uniqueId](http://api.jqueryui.com/uniqueId/)).

```
$.each(data.items, function (i, item) {
    $('<li />').uniqueId()
        .append($('<img />').attr('src', item.media.m))
        .appendTo('#images');
});
```

Assuming `#images` is an `ul` or `ol`.